# how to pass to or more list of series to set series

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

Hi I am trying to implement a combined highchart using dotnet highcharts.So I have a column chart+pie chart.
I made List allSeries = new List()for column Chart and List pieSeries = new List()for pie chart.

I dont know how to pass this  two series to to the .SetSeries() wich accepts SetSeries(Series series);
or SetSeries(Series[] seriesArray);

```
      public ActionResult Profit()
    {
        DBContext.Current.Open();
        List<RoomType> result = new List<RoomType>();
        result = RoomType.Selectcount();
        List<Series> allSeries = new List<Series>();
        List<Series> pieSeries = new List<Series>();
        List<DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point> puncte = new List<DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point>();
        string[] categories = new[] { "Ianuarie", "Februarie", "Martie", "Aprilie", "Mai", "Iunie", "Iulie", "August", "Septembrie", "Octombrie", "Noiembrie", "Decembrie" };
        object[] pointnum = new object[12];
        foreach (var j in result)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < pointnum.Length; i++)
            {
                pointnum[i] = Roomtypereservations.RoomTypeByDate(j.RoomType_ID, i + 1).FirstOrDefault().NumRezervari;
            }
            allSeries.Add(new Series
            {
                Type=ChartTypes.Column,
                Name = j.Room_Type,
                //Data = new Data(myData)
                Data = new Data(pointnum.ToArray())

            });
            pieSeries.Add(new Series
            {
                Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                Name = "Total rooms",
                Data = new Data(puncte.ToArray())
            });
            puncte.Add(new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point
            {

                Name = j.Room_Type,
                Y=13
                //Data = new Data(myData)


            }); 
        }

        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Combination chart" })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories =categories} )
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "TooltipFormatter" })
            .AddJavascripFunction("TooltipFormatter",
                                  @"var s;
                if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                   s = ''+
                      this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' fruits';
                } else {
                   s = ''+
                      this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                }
                return s;")
            .SetLabels(new Labels
            {
                Items = new[]
                                   {
                                       new LabelsItems
                                       {
                                           Html = "Total fruit consumption",
                                           Style = "left: '40px', top: '8px', color: 'black'"
                                       }
                                   }
            })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    Center = new[] { "100", "80" },
                    Size = "100",
                    ShowInLegend = false,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels { Enabled = false }
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(allSeries.Select(s => new Series { Type = s.Type, Name = s.Name, Data = s.Data }).ToArray());


        return View(chart);
```

When i am working with only one series like in my sample
 its working:
 .SetSeries(allSeries.Select(s => new Series { Type = s.Type, Name = s.Name, Data = s.Data }).ToArray());

how can i pas both pieSeries and all Series to .SetSeries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need both allSeries and pieSeries.  I would get rid of pieSeries.  You can assign as many series to your allSeries List as you need and they can be of any type.  So change your pieSeries.Add to the following:

```
allSeries.Add(new Series
{
   Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
   Name = "Total rooms",
   Data = new Data(puncte.ToArray())
})
```

Then the following statement will work and all of your required Series to the chart:

```
.SetSeries(allSeries.Select(s => new Series { Type = s.Type, Name = s.Name, Data = s.Data }).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you very much it was so simple